# I'm having more issues with defining statements

Tags: input, while-loop, undefined

I am trying to do a defining statement with an input loop. if the input is outside the statement my only issue is it repeats the input twice which is kinda weird. with the input only inside the while loop it gives the error of amt not defined.

```
    def Loan_Amount(amt):
    while True:
        amt = int(input("Please put in the loan amount you would like to take out: "))
        if amt < 500:
           print("Sorry, we don't offer loans below 500 dollars")
           continue
        elif amt >= 500:
           break
    print(Loan_Amount(amt))
```

The other way that looks weird

```
    amt = int(input('Please put in the loan amount you would like to take out: '))
    
    def Loan_Amount(amt):
    while True:
        amt = int(input("Please put in the loan amount you would like to take out: "))
        if amt < 500:
           print("Sorry, we don't offer loans below 500 dollars")
           continue
        elif amt >= 500:
           break
    print(Loan_Amount(amt))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm leaving it up incase anyone else runs into this problem but after looking at the documentation I figured it out.

```
   def Loan_Amount(prompt)
        While True:
             global amt
             amt = int(input(prompt))
             if amt < 500:
                  print("Sorry, we don't offer loans below 500 dollars")
                  continue

             else:
                  break
    Loan_Amount('Please put in the loan amount you would like to take out: ')
    print(amt)
```

I am not 100 percent sure if I am going to explain this right so take my interpretation loosly. Basically instead of having amt inside of the parenthesis like such def Loan_Amount(amt) causing it to be both a parameter and a global variable instead it is prompt and instead of typing out the input inside the loop it is typed when calling upon the statement. global amt part is in there I'm pretty sure so when amt is given a number it will make amt a global variable instead of keeping it local inside the loop so you can print it outside the loop and it is still a defined variable. Hope this helps anyone as lost as I am!